# Can't access modules when importing my own package

Tags: python

i got a directory structure, this is a simplified example:

```
project_root/
    __init__.py
    test.py
    mypack/
        __init__.py
        mymodule.py
```

`test.py` contains this:

```
from . import mypack

mypack.mymodule.some_function()
```

and mypack's `__init__.py` contains this:

```
from . import *
__all__ = ['mypack']
```

When doing this, Python tells me that 'mypack' doesn't have 'mymodule'.
I can only do `from mypack import mymodule`.
This happens both in Python 2.7 and Python 3.5.

How can I get this to work? It seems it can only be done when I install my packages, and not with project directories.

Comment: What's in the `__init__.py` file of the package?

Comment: I'm confused as to why `import mypack` doesn't throw an ImportError. That should be `from . import mypack`, should it not? Are you sure you're importing the correct `mypack` module?

Comment: @Rawing My bad, it is `from . import mypack`. I edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I added the `__init__.py` content in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the option you want to work, you have to actually import the function in the `mypack.__init__.py` file:

```
#In mypack/__init__.py
import mymodule
```

Though it can work, it is not the most pythonic way to do it, I'd recommend (and I am still sure it can be bettered):

```
# In your test.py file
import mypack.mymodule

mypack.mymodule.some_function() # Should work now
```

This way you know where your file comes from and don't have to modify your __init__.py file for it to work

Answer (score 1):

If you want your module to be accessible from the package import, you need to include it in your `__all__`:

```
# from . import *  This is prolly not needed when using __all__
__all__ = ['mymodule']
```

It appears you misunderstand how `__all__` works. You might want to see [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)